# VectorQ with "mathematical" typography

Tags: matrix, vector

Define a matrix by:

[image]

where the "mathematical" typography is crucial here.

Then `MatrixQ[mm]` yields `True` (as expected).

Moreover, multiplying (`Dot[]`) a matrix by a vector in "mathematical" typography works just fine:

[image]

However,

[image]

yields `False` (which is incorrect), even though `VectorQ[{x,y}]` yields `True`.

**Question**:  How does one get `VectorQ` to operate correctly on a "mathematical" representation of a vector?

Comment: `MatrixQ[{{x, y}}] == True; MatrixQ[Transpose[{{x, y}}]] == True;`

Comment: I assume you used the Palettes to enter the Vector? If so, it is a matrix actually. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkivb.png) it looks on the screen like one column vector.  The help on VectorQ gives similar example ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZtMh.png) I do not know if there is palettes entry that looks like Vector but is not a Matrix

Comment: @cvgmt:  Not quite applicable.  The whole point is on *typography* (the parentheses and typesetting of numbers in a column.  Your "solution" doesn't address that at all.

Comment: No.There are no column vector in Mathematica.

Comment: As far as I've seen, there is no palette entry for `{x,y}` instead of `{{x},{y}}`.

Comment: I don't use palette entry.  I use parentheses and `Control-Return`.

Comment: David, That would be the same thing as using the palette. This will create a Matrix not a vector. i.e. `{{x},{y}}` instead of `{x,y}`.  May be palette needs new entry that looks like it, but works for `{x,y}`.

Comment: The only problem I see, is should `{x,y}` display as a row vector or as a column vector? Since in Mathematica this concept do not really exist (compared to say Matlab or Fortran) and Mathematica decides if `{x,y}`  is row or column based on the context it is used.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork wouldn't all this confusion be cleared by simply evaluating your expression inside `TracePrint` or its components inside `FullForm`?

Comment: This is a 2x1 column matrix, not a vector.

Comment: @GregHurst:  VectorQ doesn't work on $1 \times 2$ lists either, in the "mathematical" typography that is the core of my question.

Comment: @rhermans:  Thanks for your thought, but no.  I'm teaching a course on *Computational Symbolic Mathematics* (using *Mathematica*), and try in every case to render output **and input** in 'mathematical' typography, to help the students think mathematically, see the relation to pencil and paper math, and so on.  For this reason I want to typeset a vertical vector as input.  But (as I wrote) `VectorQ` does not work on that representation.  Clear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I disagree with the statement that the result of `VectorQ` is *incorrect*. When using "mathematical typography" (as you call it) for entering vectors, the expression is always parsed as a matrix even if  there is only a single column

[image: Vector]

The behaviour of [`VectorQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorQ.html) is explained in the documentation with a concrete example

> These are not vectors:
>
> `VectorQ[{{1}, {2}}]`
>
> `(* False *)`

However, I agree that this behaviour might be inconvenient for teaching mathematics with Mathematica, and might also confuse beginners.

---

##### How does one get VectorQ to operate correctly on a "mathematical" representation of a vector?

There are two possible ways to get the expected behaviour:

1. Fix the parsing of "mathematical notation" so that one column is parsed into a flattened list `{1, 2, 3}` instead of `{{1}, {2}, {3}}`. You could do this with `$PreRead` by matching something like `RowBox[{"(", GridBox[ ... ], ")"}]` and then replacing it accordingly ... However, I was not able to come up with a working solution.
2. Define a new Q-function to also match non-flattened vectors:

```
MyVectorQ[expr_] := VectorQ[expr] || VectorQ[expr, Dimensions[#] == {1} &]

MyVectorQ[{1, 2, 3}]
(* True *)
MyVectorQ[{{1}, {2}, {3}}]
(* True *)
```

One could also modify the behaviour of `VectorQ`, although I absolutely advise you **not do this** because it will very likely affect other functions.

```
Unprotect[VectorQ];
VectorQ[expr_] := 
 MatchQ[expr, {args___?(Not[ListQ[#]] &)}] || 
  VectorQ[expr, Dimensions[#] == {1} &]
Protect[VectorQ];

VectorQ[{1, 2, 3}]
(* True *)
VectorQ[{{1}, {2}, {3}}]
(* True *)
```

---

Overall, both methods require to somehow modify the standard and expected behaviour of Mathematica. While this might be beneficial for teaching mathematics, I wouldn't say it is beneficial for teaching Wolfram Language. One simply has to accept and learn about this peculiarity.

Comment: Thanks Domen... thoughtful and helpful.  ($+1$, $\checkmark$). I think `VectorQ` *could* (and in my opinion *should*) apply to the "mathematical" column representation of a list of numerical values, and perhaps *WRI* will incorporate this into future versions.  Your workaround is about the best one can do in the current form of *MMa*.